# How do I center text in geom_label box in R ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using geom_label for my (gg)plots in R, I notice that there is too much space above the text than there is below. How do I align the text to be in middle of the label box?

```
x <- data.frame(x = c("Being not", "Creative"), y = c(0.5, 1), text = c(543,12345))

g <- ggplot(data=x, aes(x, y)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill=c("red4","cornflowerblue"))

g + geom_label(aes(y = -Inf, label = text), vjust = -2)

# increasing `label.padding` here to exaggerate the white space
g + geom_label(aes(y = -Inf, label = text), vjust = -2, label.padding = unit(1, "lines")
```

[image: Illustrative Sample]

Comment: I think it's an artifact of using `vjust` to position the text, rather than explicit `y` values in your data frame. If I add a column with values, say, 0.25, and use that, with `vjust = 0`, they look centered to me.

Comment: How about using `position_nudge` instead?  It doesn't work well with `y = -Inf`, but you could do `y = 0` or something and then labels would be centered.  Or, as above, simply give a `y` value for both labels.

Comment: This will work here or with stacked bars: `g + geom_label(aes(label = text), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5))`. Here, you can also just do `g + geom_label(aes(label = text, y=0.5*y))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use explicit y coordinates to place the label instead of `vnudge`

```
g + geom_label(aes(y = .25, label = text), label.padding = unit(1, "lines"))
```

[image]

**Better yet: pass a vector of y coordinates to the y `aes` to specify midpoints.**

```
g + geom_label(aes(y = c(.25, .5) label = text), label.padding = unit(1, "lines"))
```

[image]

Comment: The accepted answer does not answer the question.

> "How do I align the text to be in middle of the label box?"

Not the middle of the geom_bar

Comment: @kabammi, this answer does answer the question, as seen in its first code and figure. Although beyond the scope of the question, the second code and figure add a supplement to illustrate how the each label can move independently anywhere along the y-axis, such as the middle of each bar, while still with the text in the middle of the labels.

Comment: @LC-datascientist sure.. but only after it has now been edited! Be careful what you say.